# Example of MediaStore.Audio.Radio

Tags: java, android, offline, fm-radio

I looked everywhere for Radio examples of android but could not find anywhere.
Since it is added in API level 21 and not much of an use I think its rare in internet.

I just want to play radio in my app offline.